# Getting post by specific date in Advance Custom Field

Tags: get-posts, timestamp

How can i get movies there are today in cinema, for example my code display the movies in time that shoud apear 16 January,17 January..., how can i display only the movies in this day.

Ex: today is Wensday 16 January 2013, how can i get only the posts(movies) that shoud apear only today

If i have 2 movies that premiere is on 16 i want to display only that.

For the meta key i use a custom field -'meta_key' => 'premiera_cinema' - with this i select the day.

```
   <?php // Get today's date in the right format
    $todaysDate = date('Ymd');
    ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'meta_key' => 'premiera_cinema',
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'meta_value' => $todaysDate,
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
) ); ?>

<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$todaysDate`?

Comment: please look now

Comment: What is the date format of `premiera_cinema`? Show the field configuration... What does this query outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compare today's date to the date meta key and select posts with a dates that are **greater than or equal**:

```
'meta_compare' => '>='
```

If you want to match only today's date, change it to just **equal**:

```
'meta_compare' => '='
```